# WP7-Skydrive API Download Any file and Save Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive

I'm trying to download file on skydrive,  but it isn't working.

```
            LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
        client.DownloadCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs>(DownloadCompleted);
        client.DownloadAsync(fileid);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        void DownloadCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            IsolatedStorageFile Isofiles = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Testfile", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, Isofiles))
            {
                using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
                {
                    isoFileWriter.Write(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it mean "it isn't working"? Please add more information to your question about what's not working so we could help you.

Comment: have you tried debugging? is the DownloadCompleted raised? is the text string created from stream reader?

Comment: Yes, i have tried debugging and text string created from stream reader

Comment: Is any exception thrown? If yes, what? If no - upto what point does it work as expected? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your only getting the metadata with this line

```
client.DownloadAsync(fileid);
```

Add /content to the fileid like this to get the actual filecontent.

```
client.DownloadAsync(fileid + "/content");
```